# First Order Nonlinear Differential Equation - choosing function for closed form

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I'm working on a problem, inspired by options theory/Black-Scholes, that requires one to find a function, $ g\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)$, which has the property

$$f'(x) = \left(1+\exp\left\{c\cdot g\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)\right\}\right)^{-1},$$

has a closed-form solution. Any suggestions on $ g\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)$, where $g$ is a monotonically increasing function, that would lead to a neat closed-form solution for $f(x)$?

Comment: How about $g=0$?

Comment: Good catch! 
I should say a monotonically increasing function of f(x)/x

Comment: Let $g=k/c log x$, where k is an integer.  Not pretty, but easier.